# Вывод данных массива JSON для jQuery UI Autocomplete

Tags: autocomplete, jquery, json

Добрый вечер! Задача состоит в том, чтобы получить локальный JSON файл со списком городов и забросить его в autocomplete. Нигде нет информации именно о массиве в json - везде только пары ключ-значение. Так вот вопрос: можно ли вообще пользоваться чисто массивами в json, и если можно, в чем ошибка моего кода? 
**Это JSON**

```
    [
    "Minsk",
    "London",
    "Riga",
    "Vilnius",
    "Warszaw",
    "Paris",
    "Moscow",
    "Tallin",
    "Berlin",
    "Amsterdam",
    "Oslo",
    "Helsinki"
]
```

**JS**

```
$('#tags').autocomplete({
    source: function(request, response) {
        var result = $.ajax({
            url: '../source.json',
            method: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data) {
                var array = [];
                response($.each( data, function(item) {
                    array.push(item);
                    return array;
                }));
                return array;
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Скопировал с доки по Autocomplete:

```
<script>
  $(function() {
    var availableTags = [
      "ActionScript",
      "AppleScript",
      "Asp",
      "BASIC",
      "C",
      "C++",
      "Clojure",
      "COBOL",
      "ColdFusion",
      "Erlang",
      "Fortran",
      "Groovy"
    ];
    $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
      source: availableTags
    });
  });
  </script>
```

http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#default

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#tags').autocomplete({
    source: function(request, response) {
        var result = $.ajax({
            url: '../source.json',
            method: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data) {
                response($.map(data, function(item) {
                    return {
                        label: item,
                        value: item
                    }
                }))
            }
        });
    }
});
```

попробуйте такой вариант